# how to remove the first list in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have textfile full of this list:

```
vid._.fun None
a7maidq8_88 None
razalzahrani None
hosy777 None
saidibrahimdarban None
dr_mashhor None
mjdhmdbn None
fgdj__q8z None
fahadalwisi None
123_london None
kh_n_ali None
i7mowwd None
aszm5253553 None
afbs4982 None
algbly_3 None
al3m.bu.jassem None
auatif3252 None
classicboutique None
reema_alqabandii None
totaqlp.89 None
anonymous.q80 None
lolo_z78 None
daloola_almahmoud1977 None
nanoshope None
rayanalmalki18d None
um_barrak_alh None
maryam_jabri None
kawaiii_store kawaiii_store
the_vocalist_samah miisssamah412
_hazem_87 None
```

How to remove the left usernames, and keep the one in the right usernames "None's" using notepad++ regex?

I've tried to Use Search for `^(\S+).*` and replace with `$1` but it remove the right list, I need to remove the left list and keep the right one.

Comment: Can there be spaces inside user names? Do you want to remove lines containing `None` as right username?

Comment: @SebastianProske yes sir.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey ive tried "^(\S+).*" replaced with "$1" but it removed the left usernames, I want the right usernames.

Comment: You should add that to your question.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey Done, thank you for telling me.

Comment: Your regex is almost fine. Find `^\S+\s+` and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find What : `\S+\s+(.*)`

Replace With : `$1`

Search Mode : `Regular Expression`

Answer (score 0):

Find What: `^\w+\s+(\w+)$`

Replace With: `\1`

> Note: . matches new line should be unchecked.

This will keep the second row only.

Answer (score 0):

Just match the left and replace with nothing:

```
Find: ^.*<space>
Repl: <blank>
```

Comment: This regex doesn't work. it remove everything except last line.

Comment: replace `\s` with `\h` to exclude the newline character.